# Какая space complexity у данного алгоритма?

Tags: c#, сложность, space-complexity

```
public void ReverseString(char[] s)
{
    char savedElem;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length - i; i++)
    {
        savedElem = s[i];

        s[i] = s[s.Length - 1 - i];

        s[s.Length - 1 - i] = savedElem;
    }
}
```

Правильно я решил, что space complexity данного алгоритма O(1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В данном случае используются две дополнительные переменные. Их размер и количество не зависит от количества элементов в переданном массиве.

Таким образом `space complexity` будет константной и описывается `O(1)`